# What is a Vector2 and Vector3 in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Title says it all. I see them used in movement scripts often, if that helps. What is a Vector2 and a Vector3, the Unity docs are a bit hard to follow for new people.

Comment: https://mathinsight.org/vector_introduction  This is a basic introduction. Vectors are mostly used to represent a direction. Or in the case of a force - a direction and magnitude. I recommend that you ask on a math site about it or study vectors outside of Unity. It will be valuable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vector's are mathematical models that model both direction and magnitude. A Vector2 is 2D, and a Vector3 3D.

A vector2(1,5) is a direction with the ratio of 1 part x, and 5 parts y. E.G a line 1/6th to the right, and 5/6th's up. a negative would make the line left and down respectively.

Magnitude show's the "strength" of the direction. E.g when using forces and physics, pushing something in a vector2(1,0) is a much weaker push to the right than a vector2(100,0) even though the direction is identical.

That should be a basic theory introduction for you.

Answer (score 8):

A `Vector` is basically a **quantity** which has a **direction**: The *quantity* is referred to as the **magnitude** of the vector, the *direction* is referred to as the **normalized** vector.

*Vector* is represented using its **components**: the *projection* of the vector on each *axis* is referred to as the *components* of the vector.

[image]

A `Vector1` has a **1D direction**, like a point on a line, or the value of a steering wheel, or any real number. *e.g. (0) or (-1000)*. The magnitude of a `Vector1` equals the absolute value of the `x` component of the vector or `sqrt(x^2)`.

[image]

A `Vector2` has a **2D direction**, like a `xy` point in a 2D space, or the position of a joystick stick, or the `uv` offset of a point on a 2D texture. *e.g. (0,0) or (-1, 100)*. The magnitude of a `Vector2` equals `sqrt(x^2+y^2)`.

[image]

A `Vector3` has a **3D direction**, like a `xyz` point in a 3D space, or a color in RGB format, or a set of three numbers. *e.g. (0,0,0) or (-0.1, 3.14, 30)*. The magnitude of a `Vector3` equals `sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)`.

[image]

A `Vector4` has a **4D direction**, like a `xyzw` point in a 4D space, or a color in RGBA format, or a set of four numbers. *e.g. (0,0,0,0) or (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)*. The magnitude of a `Vector4` equals `sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)`.

[image]

Comment: So for example, if in a 2d game, I want to make a character jump, I'll use the Vector3 z axis?

Comment: @Idk in a 2D game your game objects will move in the 2D space (x,y) and you need a `vector2` for that (Jumping manipulates Y). And assigning a `vector2` to `transform.position` which is a `vector3` automatically converts it to a `vector3` with its `z` equal to `0`

Comment: @idk in a 2D game, z represents the depth

Comment: This deserves more attention, It's a great explanation!

Answer (score -1):

### Vector2

It is representation of 2D vectors and points, used to represent 2D positions, only two axis x&y.

### Code Examples

### for Positive values

Debug.log(new Vector2(1, 2) - new Vector2(3, 2));

### for Negative values

print(-new Vector2(1, 2));

### Vector3

It is representation of 3D vectors and points, used to represent 3D positions,considering x,y & z axis.

### Code Examples

Vector3  offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;

1.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed)

1. Debug.Log(Cube.transform.rotation) //cube is the Gameobject

[image: The Vector 3D response]

Comment: Probably worth explaining that vector's don't really represent points but depending on the maths you do with them can act as points would.